# Mysql join multiple tables while filling left side and check if certain row is NOT NULL

Tags: mysql

I wish to join multiple tables with the following structure:

```
Users (userId, name)
Emoticons (emoticonId, name)
UnlockedEmoticons (userId, emoticonId, name)
```

For every items, I wish to show if the certain emoticon is unlocked by the user like:

```
1(emoticonId), emoticonA(name), unlocked (userId IS NOT NULL) AS has?,
2(emoticonId), emoticonB(name), locked (userId IS NOT NULL) AS has?
```

The problem is, if there is no userId in the unlockedEmoticons, I get empty results.

```
SELECT e.*, (ue.id IS NOT NULL) AS `has`
FROM UnlockedEmoticons ue RIGHT JOIN emoticons e ON ue.emoticonId = e.emoticonId
LEFT JOIN users u ON u.id = ue.userId
WHERE uk.userId = 33
```

I tried to change the join statements orders to but no avail. Is there a way to accomplish this?

I am using mysql 5.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to include AND after the ON statements:

```
FROM UnlockedEmoticons ue RIGHT JOIN emoticons e ON ue.emoticonId = e.emoticonId AND ue.userId = #{userId}
```

and remove WHERE statements. :)